# How can i compare 3 chars by ascii code?

Tags: c++, char

I got a string of chars and I have to eliminate the biggest char alphabetically.  The rule is that I have three letters L1,L2,L3.L2 is eliminated only if is bigger than L1 and L2 alphabetically, and only the first L2 is eliminated and I would like to insert a blank space where the char is eliminated.

This would be the code I tried to make

```
cin.get(s,100);
n=strlen(s);
while(i<=n)
{
    if(((int)s[i]<(int)s[i-1]) && ((int)s[i]<(int)s[i+1]))
        strcpy(s+i,s+i+1);
        i++;
}
```

Input  `cadgfacbda`
Output `cad facbda`

I'm preety sure that i need to use a do...while syntax

Comment: As an aside: you want to define and initialize `i` before you use it.  As it stands this code won't even compile let alone work in a meaningful way.

Comment: you probably want a `for`-loop

Comment: I got everything initialized,the only problem is that i don't know how to compare the strings by ASCII

Comment: @schizoid each char in the string is ASCII, but why using strcpy

Comment: @AntiHeadshot it's by mistake,that should just overwrite the letter that i want to delete

Comment: so help you solving the problem. Itteratr over every element, and look for the index where the element with the highest ASCII value is. Then use `s[indexOfHighestElement]=' ';`

Comment: You are being inconsistent everywhere. You want to compare 3 characters? 3 numbers (you cast them to `int`)? What do you mean by "eliminate", there is no standard way to eliminate a character. The title is something very different than the example you provide.

Comment: If you need to eliminate the biggest alphabetically you will also have to consider capital and non capital letters. i.e.: What is the desired result for string `HELaP`? `HEL P` or `HELa `?

Comment: Is there a mandate in the standard that chars must be ASCII encoded, or can they still be EBCDIC?

Comment: i got only small letters

Comment: Peter, they could be anything, but ASCII feels like a pretty safe assumption these days. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Well. Until it isn't. No IBM mainframes around? I am relaly not sure. Admittedly UTF-8 is probably also quite common these days. What happens if input comes from a terminal with a UTF charset?

Comment: They are still around.  But when's the last time you actually had to write code to support EBCDIC?  I'm not even sure that I actually *had* to write code to support it 30 years ago when I was actually using IBM mainframes.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I did... we read tapes from mainframes on a linux boox end of the 90s. You know, things get used in places you wouldn't think of.

Comment: You're not wrong, but I think it overcomplicates the OP's question.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Well. Computers are unforgiving. He asks a hard (and possibly underdefined -- does he want to sort by numeric value or indeed by the ASCII value of a given char regardless of its encoding?) -- question. It's a bit like saying "use conio.h", it will just fail more rarely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about replacing your loop with this:

```
 char *biggest = NULL;
 char cBiggest = 0;
 for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
 {
      if(s[i] > cBiggest)
      {
        cBiggest = s[i];
        biggest = s+i;
      }
 }
 *biggest = ' ';
```

This uses a pointer to track the largest ASCII value found.  The largest ASCII value will be, alphabetically, the largest character.  It uses a second variable, cBiggest, to keep track of the largest character encountered so far.

After iterating over the entire string it then uses the pointer to set that character to a space.

**Please Note** I haven't tested this code at all.  You may need to tweak it.

Comment: and variable "c" is?

Comment: Whoops. :)  Corrected./  See, I told you I didn't test it. :)

Comment: shouldn't you use `' '`, because using a string can cause problems if you don't pay attention.

Comment: Yes!  Thanks.  You're teaching me to compile code before I post it. :)

Comment: `biggest = ' ';` that is a type mismatch. You probably meant `*biggest`

Comment: Ah, I saw that one before you did. ;)  It's already fixed.  Thanks Jordan.

Comment: In the if statement,how is compared the char to the int?

Comment: We're not.  We are comparing the numeric value of one char to the numeric value of another char.